# Key press events not recording when executable is run

Tags: swift, macos

I gathered some code from internet for monitoring global key down events.

It works fine when I run it through Xcode. The problem is when I run it through Terminal, it doesn't capture any events. I have enabled accessibility in the settings for both Xcode and Terminal.

Here is the code:

```
func handlerEvent(aEvent: (NSEvent!)) -> Void {

    let stringBuilder = aEvent.characters!
    print(stringBuilder, separator: "", terminator: "")


}

// MARK: Event Monitor
func listenForEvents() {
    let mask = (NSEventMask.keyDown)
    _ = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: mask, handler: handlerEvent)
}

func acquirePrivileges() -> Bool {
    let options: NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String : true]
    let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)

    if !accessEnabled {
        print("Access Denied")
    }

    return accessEnabled
}

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
                if acquirePrivileges()
        {
            print("Access Granted")
        }
        print("Starting logging")

        listenForEvents()
    }
}


let application = NSApplication.shared()

let applicationDelegate = ApplicationDelegate()
application.delegate = applicationDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
application.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this have to be a commandline app? You can generally only register application bundles (i.e. things with an Info.plist and an application identifier) to the global monitor. You probably notice that when you run this, it asks to authorize Xcode or Terminal, because that's the app you're running under. Xcode forwards the events on to you, Terminal probably doesn't.

If you can make this a regular app bundle (even without a UI), it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I think it is the only way to get my work done by building without a UI.